# read only queries on hot standby server fail due to acquiring transaction id

Tags: replication, pipelinedb

we just backed up a primary onto a hot standby server successfully. however, when we try to query to hot standby, we get the following error:

```
ERROR: cannot assign TransactionIds during recovery
```

I enabled verbose mode and see the error occurs at varsup.c:72

```
/* safety check, we should never get this far in a HS standby */ 
if (RecoveryInProgress())
   elog(ERROR, "cannot assign TransactionIds during recovery");
```

the strange thing is, if we use the psql client and issue multiple read queries, the first one will fail, but all subsequent ones will succeed.

```
pipeline=#    SELECT pg_is_in_recovery();
ERROR:  cannot assign TransactionIds during recovery
pipeline=#    SELECT pg_is_in_recovery();
 pg_is_in_recovery 
-------------------
t
(1 row)
```

using postgres 9.5.3

any ideas would be greatly appreciated it.

btw:
we have added:
`hot_standby = on` to pipelinedb.conf (equivalent to postgresql.conf)

and we have added:

```
primary_slot_name = 'replicator_slot'
primary_conninfo = 'user=username host=ip_address port=5432'
recovery_target_timeline = 'latest'
```

to recovery.conf

Comment: We're currently looking into [the issue](https://github.com/pipelinedb/pipelinedb/issues/1867) you so thoughtfully wrote up for us. I'll post an update here once it's resolved, which shouldn't be long

Answer (score -1):

Use

```
pg_ctl promote
```

to exit recovery mode and resume normal (read/write) operation.

From the [postgresql documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/app-pg-ctl.html):

```
In promote mode, the standby server that is running in the specified 
data directory is commanded to exit recovery and begin read-write 
operations.
```

Comment: thanks for the tip paul, but we dont want the hot standby to exit recovery. ideally it would always be in recovery and help the primary/master with running read only queries.